# Websphere initial load fails causing application to crash

Tags: java, websphere, corba

I am working with a large enterprise application which uses Swing for UI, EJB 2.0 as well as 3.0, hibernate,all these with a complex architecture. It uses CORBA for JNDI lookup(I assumed it because we keep getting CORBA rolled back exception). The application is running on WAS 8.0 on RAD 9.0, java 1.7 on oracle 11g.

The problem is the application crashes some times when we launch and if I restart the server without any changes in code works some times. For this initial load to happen we kill the java process, kill rad and any java process and then redo the same the application launches.

I know the question is vague, but this is my real situation. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess you have not turned of logging. Do you see something suspicious?

Comment: Are you using `launchClient`? If yes, is that process crashing or the server? What does "crashing" mean (exception, JVM crash, other)?

Comment: By crash I mean that the application is unstable. Initialisation files are not loading. Logging is turned on. Yes we are using a launch client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try clearing the class cache:
IBM How to clear the WebSphere class caches
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21607887